# What are the differences between "from" and "of"?

Tags: prepositions

Both *of* and *from* are possible, with different meanings, of course.

- > ....a magnificent picture in a book, called **True Stories of Nature**, about the primeval forest.

  This means that the stories are about Nature, they speak of Nature as a whole or they may speak of different happenings, a boa constrictor eating a prey, the birth of baby dolphin, the first flight of a sparrow.....and they are seen as manifestations of Mother Nature.
- > ....a magnificent picture in a book, called **True Stories from Nature**, about the primeval forest.

  This means that the stories are about the different things that may happen in Nature: a story about a boa constrictor eating a prey, a story about the slow growth of a little pine tree, the story of a salmon that swims against the drift in a river, the story of the birth of a baby owl.....these are all pictures taken from Nature.

Although one of my friends has already explained them, in fact I cannot yet understand this logic or argument well.

Would anyone possibly readily explain the difference between *from* and *of,* considering the bold parts?

Comment: With this sort of question, you should add your friend's explanation **and** what you found from your own independent research in dictionaries and the like, and **then** ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

The word *from* typically describes a place of origin, while *of* is more often used to relate a part to a whole or a child to a parent (either physical or abstract). In many cases these are completely interchangeable. The best way I know of to explain this is by rephrasing "X is *from* Y" as "Y *has* X". If the second phrase makes sense, then use *from*, otherwise if it makes more since to say "X is *about* Y", then use *of*.

In your case, either *from* or *of* can be appropriate. It really just depends on what you'd like to emphasize. Is it more important to highlight the origin of the stories (thus granting some ownership of the True Stories to Nature herself), or are you simply categorizing these True Stories to be about or related to Nature? If the former, use *from*; else, use *of*.

Answer (score 0):

Change the noun, *nature*, to that of *crime* and you'll see the difference in meaning more clearly.

The phrase *A true story of crime* tells us **about** an episode involving a crime whereas *A story from crime* sounds as if  *crime* is personified, we don't normally personify *crime* and as a result its meaning  sounds peculiar. *Nature* on the other hand is interpreted as being a living organism, as being alive and real, hence it is often used in a metaphorical sense.  The resulting expression, [*mother nature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Nature), is a typical example of anthropomorphism. Hence whenever we talk about *nature* being cruel or the necessity to respect *nature*, it is as if *nature* were a person.

Consequently, the phrase *True Stories from (Mother) Nature* are stories witnessed by  Nature, the stories **come from** "her". *True Stories of Nature* are stories about nature; in this case "the primeval forest".